# What is cause of segmentation fault here?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have written a small array merge procedure. On running I am getting segmentation fault. Can Anyone point out me what could have gone wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void merge(int arr[], int p, int q, int r)
{
    int L[q-p+1];
    int R[r-q];

    for(int i = p; i < r;i++)
    {
        if(i<q+1)
        {
            L[i] = arr[i];
        }
        else
        {
            R[i-q+1] = arr[i];
        }
    }

    int i = 0, j = 0,k = p;

    while(i<q-p+1 || j<r-q)
    {
        if(L[i]>R[j])
        {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }

        k++;
    }

    if(i == q-p+1)
    {
        for(;j<r-q;j++,k++)
        {
            arr[k] = R[j];
        }
    }

    if(j == r-q)
    {
        for(;i<q-p+1;i++,k++)
        {
            arr[k] = L[i];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    int a[] = {2,4,6,8,1,3,5,9};
    merge(a,0,3,7);

    for(int i = 0; i<8;i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<"\t";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Switch to `std::array` and use `.at()`, you probably have an out of bounds access, or just use a debugger.

Comment: @user657267: `std::array` is a fixed size container.

Answer (score 0):

You should step through it in a debugger.

This line of code:

```
while (i<q - p + 1 || j<r - q)
```

Will not prevent i from being >= `q-p+1` (i.e if j is still less than `r-q`). This will mean that you are reading outside of your array boundaries.

You should change it to

```
while (i<q - p + 1 && j<r - q)
```

Also note: `int L[q-p+1]` is not valid C++, it is valid C, but not C++

Comment: But since c is subset of c++ it should work in c++ as well.

Comment: @Apoorvasahay The thing is, C is not a subset of C++.

Comment: @Apoorvasahay C is **almost** a subset of C++. Example 1: conversion from `void*` to other pointer types(`int* x = malloc(sizeof(int));` - valid C, not valid C++) - C++ forbid it because it's unsafe. Example 2: VLA(`int tab[rand() % 10];` - valid C, not valid C++). C++ didn't adapt it because VLA's have problems.